# Permission denied executing any gcc-compiled c program on OS X (10.8.2) Mountain Lion

Tags: c, xcode, macos, gcc, permission-denied

When executing any C program that I have compiled with `gcc` from the terminal, I get a permission denied error.

To start, I have verified and repaired permissions on my drive (before doing this, the same problem was happening).

To illustrate and isolate the problem, I'll show you what happens with this ultra-simple Hello World program (with other programs, the same thing occurs):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

Now, I save this to my desktop as `helloworld.c`. At this point, from the desktop, an `ls -l` returns:

```
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 michael  staff  56 Mar 13 14:08 helloworld.c
```

I then compile with `gcc -c helloworld.c -o helloworld` (I've also tried compiling without the `-o` flag with the same results). No warnings or errors. An `ls -l` now returns:

```
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 michael  staff   56 Mar 13 14:08 helloworld.c
-rw-r--r--  1 michael  staff  724 Mar 13 14:16 helloworld.o
```

Attempting to execute the output of gcc, with `./helloworld.o` returns:

```
-bash: ./helloworld.o: Permission denied
```

Just for the sake of debugging, if I execute with sudo (`sudo ./helloworld.o`), it returns:

```
sudo: ./helloworld.o: command not found
```

Now, if I attempt to set the executable flag using `chmod +x helloworld.o`, as was recommended on a lot of search results I've found, `ls -l` returns:

```
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 michael  staff   56 Mar 13 14:08 helloworld.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 michael  staff  724 Mar 13 14:16 helloworld.o
```

However, attempting to execute with `./helloworld.o` now returns:

```
-bash: ./helloworld.o: Malformed Mach-o file
```

Now, for debugging sake, `where gcc` returns:

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

So, you can see that I am not using a third party `gcc`.

Does anyone know what could be the problem? I've tried searching around, but I couldn't find any working solutions. I was having this same problem earlier and have since freshly reinstalled OS X (for different reasons) and am still having this problem with a clean and organized development environment. For reference, I'm on OS X 10.8.2 and have Xcode 4.6 along with the latest version of Xcode Command Line tools (from Apple's developer website). I have not installed gcc from Homebrew or from any other third party source; it is the gcc that came with Xcode Command Line tools.

Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate you taking your time to read, diagnose and offer your help. :)

Comment: I had this issue when I did make foobar where foobar.c had an error in it. When I fixed the error, it worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're trying to execute object code (helloworld.o) rather than compile and link an executable binary. Don't use the `-c` option. Run this instead:

```
$ gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

It will be created with executable permissions. You can then run.

```
$ ./helloworld
```

as normal.

---

The reason for this is that the `-c` option tells the compiler just to *compile* the file, but not *link* it. The link process is needed to create the final executable file. If you don't supply `-c`, gcc will both compile and link for you behind the scenes.

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you very much! I'll mark your response as the answer as soon as the system allows. :)